# Как заменить char null'ом?

Tags: c#

Хочу заменить `char` на пустую, но не знаю как. Интересует что-то подобное `String.Empty`

```
private string replace(string hex, string input)
        {
            int decValue = Convert.ToInt32(hex, 16);
            string result = input.Replace((char)decValue, ' ');
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: просто удаляйте "заменяемый" символ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`String.Empty` - строка нулевой длины, символ же не может быть нулевой длины. Самое близкое, что можете использовать - `'\0'`. Но строка от этого короче не станет. Тогда уж лучше так: `string result = input.Replace(((char)decValue).ToString(), "");`

Answer (score 0):

Почему бы не использовать тогда `char?`

```
public bool IsCharIsNull(char? e)
{
 if(e == null)
{
 return true;
}
 else return false;
}
```

Comment: Например, потому, что в строке (а у ТС там строка) именно `char`'ы, а не `char?`'ы.